# Apache Commons Lang: Upgrade from 2.3 to 3.3.1 - What about UnhandledException

Tags: java, replace, unhandled-exception, apache-commons-lang

I recently upgraded the Apache Commons version of my project (commons-lang) from version 2.3 to version 3.3.1 (latest stable).

In my code there was usage of specific Exception like [UnhandledException](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException.html) and I am just wondering which is the replacement of such exception if I use the latest version because I got plenty of errors due to that usage.

There is other [Exceptions](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/package-summary.html) defined in the version 3 but nothing similar to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UnhandledException is a NestableRuntimeException, and in 3.0 they completely removed support for nested exceptions, so I don't think you're going to find a replacement:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html#Whats_gone